# BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR not found

Tags: xcode

I have an application containing embedded frameworks. I want to remove the headers from those frameworks when I build the project. However, there are other headers in the app wrapper that I do not want removed. (I am writing an integrated development environment for C and C++ that has to include headers so that the bundled compiler will work.) I have a Run Script phase that uses the Unix `find` tool to locate and remove the `Headers` and `PrivateHeaders` directories (and the symlinks that point to them) from the embedded frameworks. It works fine when I am building for use with Xcode's debugger.

However, when I use Xcode's Archive command to perform a release, the `${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}` variable is no longer expanded correctly. Investigation indicates that it points to a directory that does not exist. Presumably Xcode deleted this directory automatically during the archive procedure, before I can open it in the Finder and see its contents.

How can I get the path to the `.app` package directory in a Run Script build phase that works correctly while creating an Xcode archive? I can then remove the headers from within the embedded frameworks by using `find` and the `${FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH}` variable.

I have already tried to remove the headers using a post-action in the Xcode scheme, but that won't work properly, as it removes **all** header files, not just those within the embedded frameworks. This is because scheme post-actions can't find the `.app` directory. (I have tried using the "Provide Build Settings From" pop-up menu, and I have verified through `printenv` that it does export the settings properly, but the `.app` directory still can't be found.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out for myself. I went into the scheme I'm using when I archive my project and added a Run Script post-action under Archive. Here is the contents of the script I used:

`find "${ARCHIVE_PRODUCTS_PATH}/${INSTALL_DIR}/${FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH}" \

-name "Headers" -exec rm -r {} \;

find "${ARCHIVE_PRODUCTS_PATH}/${INSTALL_DIR}/${FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH}" \

-name "PrivateHeaders" -exec rm -r {} \;`

Note that if you do this for yourself, you must replace the fictitious `INSTALL_DIR` variable with the location of your app wrapper. You can find this in the Build Settings screen for your application target; look for "Installation Directory". (The name of the app wrapper is part of the `FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH` variable, which is why you didn't see it above.)